# toast displaying problem + android

Tags: android, toast

Toast is displaying on emulator i.e "SMS sent".etc.

but it is not displaying on HTC device.

```
    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)    
    {                
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";        
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";         
        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,new Intent(SENT), 0);
        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    //---when the SMS has been sent--- 

    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
    {            
        @Override            
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
        {      
            String idtochange= Integer.toString(prefName);
            switch (getResultCode())
            {                   
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:                        
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    con.onUpdateSet("master_table", "remark", "result_ok", new String[] {"msg_id"},new String[] {idtochange});
                    break;

                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:                       
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    con.onUpdateSet("master_table", "remark", "generic_failure", new String[] {"msg_id"},new String[] {idtochange});
                    break;

                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    con.onUpdateSet("master_table", "remark", "no_serivce", new String[] {"msg_id"},new String[] {idtochange});
                    break;

                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    con.onUpdateSet("master_table", "remark", "null_pdu", new String[] {"msg_id"},new String[] {idtochange});
                    break;                    

                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    con.onUpdateSet("master_table", "remark", "radio_off", new String[] {"msg_id"},new String[] {idtochange});
                    break;               
            }           
        }


    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    //---when the SMS has been delivered---

    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
    {            
        @Override            
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
        {                
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;                    

                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;                      
            }           
        }        

    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    System.out.println("contactsssss"+phoneNumber);
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

Plzz help me for this...

Comment: accept some answers... and are you sure that the getResultCode() returns the correct value?! Some tip: never create a switch statement without a "default" case...

Comment: yes its working in emulator but not displaying on device

Comment: and thanx to reminding to include default case

Comment: hi warren, i think its a problem of resultcode which is not working for device, from last week i am still stuck for this problem. so will you please help me out. what should i wrote instead of resultcode so that it can work for device as well.

Comment: are you sure that the result code is wrong? Have you debugged on the device?

Comment: yes i have debug it but it is not going inside that part

Comment: the sms is being sent properly from device but it is not giving any notification like sms is sent or deliver

Comment: what is the returned value of getResultCode()?

Comment: for result_ok it is giving -1 and for error 1

Comment: and he is not stepping into the case?

Comment: yes as when i did on emulator it stepping into the case but not with device

Comment: have you debugged on device, too? Find out if the result code is the same on emulator/device and step through the method completely. Check the values and find out if he steps into which case... if the values are the same and the cases are still ignored... well than I am a bit lost :/

Comment: i have checked this from all aspect but will try once again and really thank for ur positive support

Answer (score 1):

Put `arg0` instead of `getBaseContext()`.

Comment: hii elijah, i putted arg0 instead of getBaseContext() but still not working. Toast not coming on device

Comment: Weird. Do you see it throw any exception in the LogCat?